# How to resolve ts(2339) using generic

Tags: typescript

I'm starting working with Generics and apparently, my type interference is not working. I have the following setup (types/interface/function)

[TypeScript Playground link if preferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEC2dgBsAKcAnrgPZwAmyA3gLABQyyUECwADsBOAFzIDOYKKADmAbgZN+AVwBGAK1Zg+g4SHGTks0hSIqhoifQC+DBqEixEKVAGVM-QiXJU6jZOwAWpEBABy0piy0PpqGu7auqGiDKb0DGBE7Ch+pGDAMMAIcOk+TmSUyAC8aFg4BMQFVAA+aPaOlS5m9BbQ8EhoqemZ2bkgACI5cAA8ACrIEAAekCAU-MhdGVk5wHmNlAB8NJqJyXwA5OgAsgCCqAAy+8i1+7ZHtlc3+ACqtgASAPp+APKjqABiqAAwic-t8-PsjEx2OsKHxRkY4gwED5BMgRNxoDkIPkXGU8MVkAAKACUfAw2DwuMKRS2biYTBYYGkUBA23cDIZLDYnG4ymQ+0ggggAAEYKRSAA6FGYSWyKD7AA0mk5UjkigQ-P2-2+3yVKtVkT0AoAQicAEr6jnIOJI+gokBojG+KDY6kUeqE0nk+ru4p0g1Mlls+mq6HeXwBIIhAUARgATABmAAsAFYAGwAdgAHABOK1hphGg5mgBaBYZtuaDrRFGA-BhYAQnmgXrJnTSS16qwGQ2Gix6KzWzk2AG0ALr+9mcoOs5Cjg2c0OFhm7CB8ABExzO5w3yutK5hI7h6Mxrsg7vxuFJi8r+5Xy5XyDXBzuD3vT+hsL4zqxF9h9Q3gelYGuOsTVqiYDICAnaDn08wlHWDY5M20CkkYMHdMs8GjgADOOkpHlUkrchwXDgEAA)

```js
interface IEmailPayload {
  recipient: string;
  subject: string;
  body: string;
}

interface ISmsPayload {
  phoneNumber: string;
  body: string
}

type NotificationPayload = IEmailPayload | ISmsPayload

interface INotificationData<T extends NotificationPayload> {
  type: 'EMAIL' | 'SMS' | 'PUSH_NOTIFICATION';
  payload: T;
}

const generatePayloadEmail = (): IEmailPayload => {
    return {
        recipient: 'teste@foo.com.br',
        subject: 'FOO',
        body: 'BAR',
    }
}

const generatePayloadSms = (): ISmsPayload => {
    return {
        phoneNumber: '123456789',
        body: 'BAZ',
    }
}

const dispatcher = (): INotificationData<NotificationPayload>[] => {
    return [
        {
            type: "EMAIL",
            payload: generatePayloadEmail()
        },
        {
            type: 'SMS',
            payload: generatePayloadSms()
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to invoke `dispatcher` and dynamically access the properties of payload

```js
const notifications = dispatcher();
notifications[0].payload.recipient
```

But an error is thrown on the `.recipient`

```
Property 'recipient' does not exist on type 'NotificationPayload'.
  Property 'recipient' does not exist on type 'ISmsPayload'.(2339)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`in`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) operator can be used to narrow the type. The problem is `notifications[0].payload` is a union of two different types (`IEmailPayload` and `ISmsPayload`).

But `recipient` only exists on one of them. This could lead to actual runtime issues so in addition to fixing the type error it's also a good runtime check.

```
const notifications = dispatcher();
const { payload } = notifications[0];

if ("recipient" in payload) {
    const recipient = payload.recipient;
}

if ("phoneNumber" in payload) {
    const phoneNumber = payload.phoneNumber;
}
```

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VmHQWS0cqwA2gBdV1MmkQOkM5A9jUMb3phhbCC8ABEB2OJwXspnEKhvEtaMgtuxuEJk+QhnX6enM7nu2utzPG7cW+RqOte6hNSPM+Mrj70UL5uLIANh2XTTIUpblpkVbQIS4hmki1APt2VCGLigHtPMIE9gADH24imDA+ILqy7CcOAC7IKAiHlASQ4MHBxbEey4C4pCSHCoxpFgHC+GER4Xi+P4gRQORlGsdRtHIPRvr8QGQksVCwp8f6gnQEYQA)